# Kaehler form on weighted projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

The Kaehler potential for the standard Fubini-Study Kaehler form in projective space $\mathbb{C} P^n$ is given by:

$$\log(\sum_{i=0}^n |z_i|^2)).$$

What is the analogous formula for a Kaehler potential in a weighted projective space  $\mathbb{C} P(m_0, \ldots, m_n)$ with weights $m_0, \ldots, m_n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$? That is, $\mathbb{C} P(m_0, \ldots, m_n) = (\mathbb{C}^{n+1} \setminus \{0\})/\sim$ where $(z_0, \ldots, z_n) \sim (\lambda^{m_0}z_0, \ldots, \lambda^{m_n}z_n)$ 
for any $0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Of course the weighted projective space is usually singular, and we are only asking for Kaehler potential in its smooth locus.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can get this just by following the Marsden-Weinstein reduction procedure using the obvious circle generated by the quotient action you have, but setting $|\lambda|=1$.  Have you tried this?

Comment: @Robert Thanks, yes I noticed that but didn't know what the resulting Kaehler potential is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weighted projective spaces are the simplest projective toric varieties and you can find the Kahler potential of singular toric varieties [here](http://msp.org/pjm/2008/238-1/pjm-v238-n1-p03-p.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

See page 21 of "Weighted projective embeddings, stability of orbifolds and constant scalar curvature Kähler metrics" by Ross-Thomas for a definition, they also discuss some other definitions.

http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5214